# We already have a registered user with this email address. Log in to connect your GitHub account

Tags: github, netlify

I'am trying to host my porfolio website using Netlify but its shows me an error: We already have a registered user with this email address. Log in to connect your GitHub account.

Comment: Okay, so... do you already have a Netlify account? Please read [ask]. We only know what you tell us.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I just started getting it out of nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

[May be you might have unlinked the bitbucket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlZjE.png)

In that case go ahead and click on forget password in netlify. Reset the password. Try to login using email and password in the netlify app. Go back to Connected Apps Section https://app.netlify.com/user/settings here and re link your bitbucket/github account. Then you will get back the access to netlify.

Answer (score 0):

By signing in to Netlify via email click on forgot password

go to->https://app.netlify.com->login->enter email->go to forget password      ->To reset your password,enter the email address you use to sign in->you will get a mail from netlify "Click the button below to reset"->reset the password  ->login

then this issue will be resolved

Answer (score 0):

Go to login with email-->Reset your password-->Refresh you tab-->Again try to login with email with your reset password